# Parametrization of cubic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

A parametrization of quadratic fields is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$, where $m\ne1$ is a squarefree integer. That is, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ is a quadratic field as $m$ varies, and all quadratic fields are included. There is another parametrization of quadratic fields, given by the 1-1 correspondence between $m$ and fundamental discriminants $d$. In particular, for each fundamental discriminant $d$ there is exactly one quadratic field of that discriminant.

Is there a similar parametrization for cubic fields?

Comment: Kummer theory generalizes your parametrization of the quadratic fields. A special case of Kummer theory says that if $K$ is a field with characteristic different from a prime $p$, and if $K$ contains all the $p^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity, then the extensions of $K$ with Galois group $C_p$ (cyclic of order $p$) are parametrized by non-trivial elements of $K^\times/K^{\times p}$, where $K(\sqrt[p]a)$ corresponds to $a \in K^\times/K^{\times p}$.

Comment: I believe if $K/\Bbb Q$ is a cubic extension and $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ then $\Bbb Q(\omega,\alpha)/\Bbb Q(\omega)$ is still a cubic extension... in that case $\Bbb Q(\omega,\alpha) = \Bbb Q(\omega,(p+q\omega)^{1/3})$ for some $p,q \in \Bbb Z$ for a choice of the cube root by Kummer theory... but I also suspect that it is possible to have $\Bbb Q(\omega,\alpha) = \Bbb Q(\omega,\beta)$ with $\Bbb Q(\alpha) \ne \Bbb Q(\beta)$

Comment: If $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q$ is cubic, i.e. $f(\alpha) = 0$ for cubic $f$, then we have two situations depending on the discriminant of $f$: if the discriminant is a perfect square, then $K$ has only one conjugate (itself); otherwise, $K$ has three conjugates. Using this, we can shift the question to classifying splitting fields of (irreducible) cubic polynomials.

Comment: An elementary observation is that if $K/\Bbb Q$ is cubic then $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ for every $\alpha \in K \setminus \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Kenny Lau: Thanks for the answers. Are there isomorphic unequal cubic fields?

Comment: I already answered you: if the discriminant is a perfect square, then $K$ has only one conjugate, i.e. it can only be embedded to $\Bbb C$ one way; otherwise it can be embedded to $\Bbb C$ three ways.